# add python interpreter to javascript

Tags: javascript, interpreter

I want to develop an application like where user writes Python code in textarea and when clicks execute the output will be displayed in frame.

So here we need

1. A Text area box(which is basic and easy to create)
2. frame next to text area to display output(mostly i do with the "simplegui" library)
3. Interpreter to interpret the code and display output

I don't know how to add interpreter to the Javascript code and display the output in frame

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a JavaScript implementation of Python called [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/) that might do everything you are looking for

Comment: post this as a answer.I will accept this and thx

Answer (score 1):

If you need a suggestion then I can suggest you something.

1. Create a textarea, add the facility for the user to write the python code in it.
2. Let him submit the code to the server.
3. On the server-side, execute it using some sort of Python Compiler or something like that. Execute it, and see for any sort of errors.

If there are some errors you can show those errors inside the `iframe` alongwith the line.

Your Server would provide you with the Line number, and the detailed information about the Exception. You can show that to the user as a Response. But remember to catch that thrown exception, the code must be inside a

```
try {
  /* code that the user wrote here */
} catch (Exception e) {
  /* show the e.Message */
}
```

Block. Then the user would be notified. And he can edit it and so on.

But remember, it would take a long time to get complete! So, just sit back and keep coding.

Good luck!

Comment: You're most welcome! However, that was an answer as a suggestion :)